# What are those characters in a regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I found this regex that works correctly but I didn't understand what is `#` (at the start) and at the end of the expression. Are not `^` and `$` the start/end characters?

```
preg_match_all('#^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$#', $s, $matches);
```

Thanks

Comment: Good introduction to regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and for PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php and http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matched pattern contains many `/`, thus the `#` is used as regex delimeter. These are identical

```
/^something$/
```

and

```
#^something$#
```

If you have multiple `/` in your pattern the 2nd example is better suited to avoid ugly masking with `\/`. This is how the RE would like like with using the standard `//` syntax:

```
/^\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/$/
```

Comment: They are called *delimiters*: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Answer (score 1):

**About `#`:**

That's a [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) of the regular expression itself. It's only meaning is to tell which delimiter is used for the expression. Commonly `/` is used, but others are possible. PCRE expressions need a delimiter with `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`.

**About `^`:**

Inside [character classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) (`[...]`), the `^` has the meaning of *not* if it's the first character.

```
[abc]   :  matching a, b or c
[^abc]  :  NOT matching a, b or c, match every other character instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Also # at the start and the end here are custom regex delimiters. Instead of the usual `/.../` you have `#...#`. Just like perl.

Answer (score 0):

These are delimiters.  You can use any delimiter you want, but they must appear at the start and end of the regular expression.

Please see this documentation for a detail insight in to regular expressions:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use pretty much anything as delimiters. The most common one is `/.../`, but if the pattern itself contains `/` and you don't want to escape any and all occurrences, you can use a different delimiter. My personal preference is `(...)` because it reminds me that `$0` of the result is the entire pattern. But you can do anything, `<...>`, `#...#`, `%...%`, `{...}`... well, almost anything. I don't know exactly what the requirements are, but I think it's "any non-alphanumeric character".

Answer (score 0):

Let me break it down:

`#` is the first character, so this is the character used as the delimiter of the regular expression - we know we've got to the end when we reach the next (unescaped) one of these

`^` outside of a character class, this means the beginning of the string

`/` is just a normal 'slash' character

`([^/]+)` This is a bracketed expression containing at least one (`+`) instance of any character that *isn't* a / (`^` at the beginning of a character class inverts the character class - meaning it will only match characters that are not in this list)

`/` again

`([^/]+)` again

`/` again

`$` this matches the end of the string

`#` this is the final delimeter, so we know that the regex is now finished.